Is it possible to drag and drop videos into a TinyMCE 6.6.2 editor?
I have set it up so people can drag and drop images, and upload videos by add media then upload, but I can't figure out how to make it possible to drag and drop videos. Is it possible and if so how do I do it? I'm currently on TinyMCE 6.6.2.
